# Bash Script to Find a Symbol in a Substantial Amount of .jar Files

Tags: bash, jar

In my mind, this should find the symbol I am looking for. Instead it does not find the symbol. Where am I going wrong? I know the symbol exists in one of the .jar files.

```
  1 ARRAY=(`find ${PWD} -name '*.jar'`);
  2 SYMBOL=$1;
  3 for i in ${ARRAY[@]};
  4 do
  5     JAR=`jar -tf $i`;
  6     GREPED=`echo ${JAR} | grep -s ${SYMBOL} | tr -d ' '`;
  7     if [ "${GREPED}" != "" ]; then
  8         echo $GREPED
  9     fi
  7 done
```

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the jar command options?

Say I download the android SDK for fun and run a tool on it that says it cant find a given class com.android.email.mail.Flag. So I run the above script with:

```
$ ./script.sh Flag
```

This should printh out the output of the `jar` command. If I wanted the jar file line 8 above would be

`echo $i`.

Comment: What do you mean by "symbol"? `jar -tf ...` lists the *files* that are included in the `.jar` file, which in some cases (class names mostly) may be somewhat related to the symbols, but they're not the same thing. I don't know of a particular way to find symbol names from a `.jar` file (or a `.class` file for that matter).

Comment: For example I am using a static analyzer that is complaining about several 'references to java classes' could not be resolved. One of those being 'com.android.email.mail.Flag'. I want to know where this class or symbol is defined. Which jar, so I can append to classpath.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to include example inputs and required outputs. What is coming out of one of your itterations of `JAR=...`? (Use modern command substition with `JAR=$(jar -tf $i)` ). And finally, please don't make people read thru clarifcations of your question in these ill-formatted comments! OK?!  Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jar usage seems ok, but there are too many variables, arrays, pipes that could have been avoided.

The following should work for you:

```
for i in `find ${PWD} -name "*.jar"`; do
  jar -tf $i | grep -qs $1 && echo $i
done
```

This would list the jar file(s) containing the symbol.